# What does the word "bust" mean in the phrase "housing bust"?

Tags: meaning

I somehow know the concept (the housing crisis that happened in the US), but I don't know the exact meaning of "bust" here.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "bust" refers to the ideas of "boom and bust," which are the upturns and downturns, respectively, in the [business cycle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_cycle)

Comment: Does it mean bankruptcy?

Comment: No, not exactly, although it may lead to bankruptcy. It is a general downturn in the market you are speaking of.

Comment: thanks a lot 